# Why do controls get populated with postback data twice - during LoadPostBack and during

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, postback, viewstate

Controls are populated with postback data during *LoadPostBack data Stage*. If dynamic control is not created and added to control tree during *OnInit* stage, but later, then control won’t get populated with postback data, as evident by the following code, where *Label1* will display an empty string:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    TextBox textB;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textB = new TextBox();
        textB.ID = "dynamicTextC";
        Panel1.Controls.Add(textB);
        Label1.Text = textB.Text; // displays an empty string
    }
```

But if I put *Label1.Text = textB.Text;* inside event handler subscribed to textB’s *TextChanged event*, then *Label1* will display text user entered into *textB*. Now that suggests that controls are populated with same postback data twice – during *LoadPostBack data Stage* and during *Raise Postback Events stage*. 
So why does control need to be populated with same postback data twice?

BTW - I realize that during *Raise Postback Events stage* control compares postback value to postback value from previous page load and then decides if event needs to be raised

```
    TextBox textB;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textB = new TextBox();
        textB.ID = "dynamicTextC";
        Panel1.Controls.Add(textB);

        textB.TextChanged += textB_TextChanged;         
    }


    protected void textB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = textB.Text; // Label1 displays value user
                                     entered into textB
    }
```

thanx

EDIT:

> The control will get created and will be part of viewstate (because it is a server-side control. Hence, it need not be created again on postback)

That's not what happens, at least in my case TextBox dissapears on a postback.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should put this code under the check

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
 textB = new TextBox();
 textB.ID = "dynamicTextC";
 Panel1.Controls.Add(textB)
}
```

EDIT: The control will get created and will be part of viewstate (because it is a server-side control. Hence, it need not be created again on postback)

Try seeing the HTML markup it generates when the page is loaded for the first time & next time to understand the markup text for "dynamicTextC".

Comment: I don't understand. Why should I put it inside 'if' statement?

Comment: Ahhh, the dreaded if(!IsPostBack).  God I'm glad I'm using MVC now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific reason why you do not want to create the dynamic Control in Page_Init? This code seems to work:

```
  protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    textB = new TextBox();
    textB.ID = "dynamicTextC";
    Panel1.Controls.Add(textB);
  }


  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Label1.Text = textB.Text;
  }
```

Comment: I know that above code would work. But my question was more about what's going on under the hood and reasons why controls get populated with postback data twice